# Erro 500 ao consumir webservice NFeDistribuicaoDFe

Tags: nfe

Todos os serviços estão funcionando no meu componente, somente esse serviço da erro ao tentar consumir, segue meu `XML soap` que estou enviando

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soap:Header>

            <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe">
                <cUF>24</cUF>
                <versaoDados>1.00</versaoDados>
            </nfeCabecMsg>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>

            <nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe">
               <distDFeInt versao="1.00"  xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" >
                   <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                   <cUFAutor>24</cUFAutor>
                   <CNPJ>35744157000106</CNPJ>
                   <distNSU>
                      <ultNSU>0</ultNSU>
                   </distNSU>
              </distDFeInt>
            </nfeDadosMsg>

        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

O XML de retorno é

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <soap:Code>
            <soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value>
         </soap:Code>
         <soap:Reason>
            <soap:Text xml:lang="en">Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</soap:Text>
         </soap:Reason>
         <soap:Detail />
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

O que está de errado com meu XML de envio? sendo que é o mesmo processo de geração do XML para os demais serviços que estão funcionando.

Alguém tem um XML de exemplo SOAP de envio de `NFeDistribuicaoDFe` funcionando?

Webservice :

```
hom.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/NFeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx
```

Nota técnica utilizada

http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=2ZkcHOdpHs= (NT2014.002_v1.01_WS_Distribuicao_DFE.pdf)

Comment: Se você estiver usando o Visual Studio adicione a referencia ao Webservice, ele vai criar todas as classes referente ao Webservice. Faça um debug usando o NFeDistribuicaoDFe, ai você poderá ver como é feito o envio.

Comment: Estou usando o Python, nao tem como eu fazer isso

Answer (score 0):

Cara, compara com esse aqui e você vai conseguir achar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap12:Header>
        <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe">
            <cUF>91</cUF>
            <versaoDados>1.00</versaoDados>
        </nfeCabecMsg>
    </soap12:Header>
    <soap12:Body>
        <nfeDistDFeInteresse xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe">
            <nfeDadosMsg>
                <distDFeInt xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="1.00">
                    <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
                    <cUFAutor>35</cUFAutor>
                    <CNPJ>CNPJ DA EMPRESA</CNPJ>
                    <distNSU>
                        <ultNSU>000000000000001</ultNSU>
                    </distNSU>
                </distDFeInt>
            </nfeDadosMsg>
        </nfeDistDFeInteresse>
    </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: Pode quebrar esse XML em várias linhas, por gentileza?

Comment: Prontcho! @ThiagoLunardi